# Easy way to switch input languages for all windows in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, input-languages

I made the 'mistake' of switching to Dvorak a number of years ago and now I'm encountering a lot of difficulties pairing with other developers at work on Windows as XP made the amazing decision to only allow input language switching on a per window basis.

I'm wondering if there's a script or hidden feature that I'm unaware of that would allow me to easily switch the input language on all windows (including CMD prompts!) so that pairing will be easier.

I'd prefer something that I can trigger via a quick hotkey like Macs supports.

Thoughts?

Comment: Oh, how I wish Mac worked the same way as Windows. While chatting in one window in one language and typing code in a different program in another window, it's a royal pain to have to switch languages back and forth.

Comment: It used to be the case, and I can't find it anymore, that Macs supported both options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I experienced with windows keyboard layouts.

If you click on the language tool bar, and settings. You will show up the configuration screen where you can add/remove the keyboard layouts.

The first block let's you choose the default input layout. That does not impact still opened windows, but new one should used the new default.

I do not know of a method that lets you switch all current windows to other layouts instantly. I still do it with my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Unfortunately.